# mongodb exclude result base on value of certain field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

`find({})` will get all items, how to skip certain item? I'm using moongse.

for example I have below document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a5e281a4ef2f71ca6bc8"), 
    "image" : "", 
    "name" : "Food", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("576faeccd141201df147a5"), 
    "image" : "", 
    "name" : "Something", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5775128ea45e34cf4a7512"), 
    "image" : null, 
    "name" : "Uncategorized", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}

db.find({"user_id":user_id}).exec(callback);
```

how to skip the 3rd item? where by catching its name, means I want to skip finding item which its name is equal to `Uncategorized`.

Comment: You can use `$ne` like `db.collection.find({name:{$ne: "Uncategorized"}})`

Comment: @Vishwas don't have to specify name field at all?